# Parameter value passed to Crystal Report from SQL stored procedure not retrieving the records from the table

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have this Winforms application in C# and I'm passing parameter value to my stored procedure and it works fine but when it comes to my crystal report, it seems that the parameter value passed from stored procedure to Crystal Report is not working, it is not displaying other records from its table.

Whatever values I'm passing to my parameter, Crystal Reports still displays the default value I entered when it requires me to enter values on the "Enter Values" field for the parameter. I tried to refresh the report, repeat the process of creating the report and even setting the param value to NULL but same result. Please help, thank you.

Here's my code (C#):

```
public void loadReport_SalesInvoiceCust()
{  
    // DISPLAY RECORDS TO MY CRYSTAL REPORT BASED FROM MY PARAMETER VALUES USING STORED PROC
   try
   {
       ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
       cryRpt.Load("C:\\MARIONNELEIGH_TRADING_REPORTS\\SalesInvoiceCust.rpt");

       SqlConnection connectionstring = connectionString.Getconnection();

       SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_Display_SalesInvoiceCust", connectionstring);
       comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@po_num", po_num);

       crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
       cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("rommel", "_Savior0914_", "LAPTOP-3OST534M\\SQLEXPRESS", "MARIONNELEIGH_TRADING");

       crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Display_SalesInvoiceCust] 
    @po_num varchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM SALES_INVOICE 
    WHERE PO_Number = @po_num
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Did you open the rpt file?

Comment: Yes the rpt file is opening, my only problem is, the report is not displaying the records based on the parameter values coming from my stored proc in sql server